# Comparing the amount of day in python with Pandas from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have a large CSV file from which I want to select a certain column, read the dates from it and compare them to today. I read the Pandas documentation and I used to_datetime to convert the column to datetime format, but I get a runtime error 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'' Is my whole logic of converting dates flawed or am I just misusing the to_datetime. This is my code so far:

```
`df = pd.read_csv('roadData.csv',delimiter = ';',encoding = "latin1",error_bad_lines=False)
thisDate = datetime.date.today()
correctCars.dateRegistered = correctCars.dateRegistered.apply(str)
paivat = pd.to_datetime(correctCars.dateRegistered, errors='coerce')
fiveYears = paivat[(paivat.days - thisDate.days >= 0) & (paivat.days - thisDate.days <= 1825)]
print(fiveYears.count())
`
```

Comment: Also, you could convert to datetime when reading your CSV. Use `parse_dates='ensirekisterointipvm'` when calling `read_csv`.

Comment: Note: Using `days` is appropriate for timedelta objects, not datetime objects.

Answer (score 4):

If large data is possible use parameter `usecols` for filtering only some column(s) and for filtering [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
paivat = pd.read_csv('roadData.csv',
                     sep = ';',
                     encoding = "latin1",
                     error_bad_lines=False, 
                     usecols=['dateRegistered'],
                     parse_dates=['dateRegistered'])

#if parse_dates doesnt return datetimes
#paivat = pd.to_datetime(paivat.dateRegistered, errors='coerce')

#for compare need datetime
thisDate = datetime.datetime.now()

#get days
d = (paivat.dateRegistered - thisDate).dt.days
#filtering
fiveYears = paivat[d.between(0, 1825)]
```

Or:

```
fiveYears = paivat[(d >= 0) & (d <= 1825)]
```

If need only count:

```
print (d.between(0, 1825).sum())
```

Or:

```
print (((d >= 0) & (d <= 1825)).sum())
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import datetime

temp=u"""dateRegistered;col
2017-11-25;0
2017-12-26;1
2017-12-27;2
2017-11-28;3
2017-11-29;4
2017-11-30;5
2017-11-01;7
2017-11-02;8
2017-11-03;9"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'roadData.csv'
paivat = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                     sep = ';',
                     encoding = "latin1",
                     error_bad_lines=False, 
                     usecols=['dateRegistered'],
                     parse_dates=['dateRegistered'])
```

---

```
thisDate = datetime.datetime.now()

d = (paivat.dateRegistered - thisDate).dt.days
print (d)
0    14
1    45
2    46
3    17
4    18
5    19
6   -10
7    -9
8    -8
Name: dateRegistered, dtype: int64

print (d.between(0, 15).sum())
1
```